# Java FileOutputStream to C:\ in Win8

Tags: java, windows, fileoutputstream

I have Java Desktop Application about statistic data generator. Application connect some DB and fetch data. Fetched datas writing to xls file and created in c:\examplefile.xls

Application succesfully working and create desired file in c:\examplefile.xls in my Laptop which running Win7.

But some Win8 and Win7 users report, application succesfully opened and working and last coming information Jpanel shows "XLS file created under C:\examplefile.xls" but when users go to C: drive can't see xls files. I suspect some writing restriction in their laptop. I try turn off UAC and restart but not help.

I use below code for FileOutputStream;

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\"+getFileString()+".xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
stmt.close();
con.close();
```

I dont share any code because application working succesfully in my laptop or someones laptop.

Any idea appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need administrator permission in order to save files in the partition where Windows is installed. Run your program as Administrator or change the location where the file is saved.

Comment: This is the drawback when you hardcode a path in your application! Why not use a file chooser for prompting the user where he wants to samve his file? Anyways, use the File class for checkeing for permissions `File#canWrite` and so on.

Comment: Use not root path of the c:.  some like: c:\folder1\file.xls"